# What is the average stat change after Pokemon Evolution?

Tags: pokemon-series

There's a pokemon I think should  evolve, so I'm making my own fake one, and I'm doing everything about it, like base stats and move pool and all.

So what I want to know is how much does each base stat change after a pokemon evolves.

For example, Bulbasaur has base stats of `45 49 49 65 65 45`. Ivysaur's base stats are `60 62 63 80 80 60` and the differnces are `15 14 15 15 15 15`. What I want to know is the average change across all Pokemon using this method of calculation.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a question about creating your own Pokemon, not a question about the game itself.

Comment: It depends, there are Pokemon that doesn't change at all after evolution (Scyther and Scizor have both 500 total), and Pokemon that change a lot (Magikarp has 200 total, Gyarados has 540).

Comment: @Yuuki I disagree. While he states his intention is to create his own Pokemon, the question in itself is not about that, but about a technical fact that can be calculated. For the record, I also disagree with the closing as too broad because while you need to look at lots of data in order to correctly answer the question, there is exactly one possible correct answer and it contains 6 values, possibly not even that. A good answer would elaborate a little and consider edge cases, but that's about it. Clearly not too broad.

Comment: @scenia He has a specific pokemon he wants changed, but his question is about the average across ALL pokemon.  That's why it's way too broad.

Answer (score 4):

I gathered the information on pokemon stats and evolution lines from bulbapedia (Up to gen VI, or #721), and threw it all into a spreadsheet to do some calculations.

Here is the relevant table of stat changes when evolving. Results are rounded to nearest integer.

[image]

Note that your desired values for all evolutions are

```
25  28  23  27  25  20
```

Mega evolutions were not included, and they will always increase the base stat total by 100 (but individual stats could decrease).

As a side note, a new (non-mega) evolution should probably have no more than 600 total stats, as this is the value for "pseudo-legendaries", which are the typical peak for non-legendary pokemon.

Sources:

1 - [Pokemon Stats](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/List_of_Pok%C3%A9mon_by_base_stats_(Generation_VI-present))

2 - [Evolution Lines](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/List_of_Pok%C3%A9mon_by_evolution_family)

3 - [Pseudo-Legendaries](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pseudo-legendary_Pok%C3%A9mon)

Comment: One exception of note: "Alakazam is the only Pokémon whose base stat total does not increase by exactly 100 points upon Mega Evolving, gaining only 90 points overall."

Comment: Any chance you would share your spreadsheet (as a .csv file for instance)?

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell you the average stats per evolution, but here's the average stats for all pokemon and fully evolved pokemon:

> **Attack**
>   The average Attack stat is 75 for all Pokémon, and the average for all fully evolved Pokémon is 90.
>   **Defense**
>   The average Defense stat is 70 for all Pokémon, and the average for all fully evolved Pokémon is 83.
>   **Special Attack**
>   The average Special Attack Stat is 69 for all Pokémon, and the average for all fully evolved Pokémon is 83.
>   **Special Defense**
>   The average Special Defense stat is 69 for all Pokémon, and the average for all fully evolved Pokémon is 83.
>   **Speed**
>   The average Speed stat is 66 for all Pokémon, and the average for all fully evolved Pokémon is 78.

[Source](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Stats#Attack)

Comment: What's the number for hp btw?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your current approach will get you what you want. Using an average on all evolved Pokemon will get you...well, an average evolved Pokemon. Evolution can entirely change the way a monster is used. I would recommend using the information from Pokemon builds that fall within a single **class** and possibly further narrow your numbers to a particular **tier**. Also, you may want to keep in mind that stats aren't the only thing that determine the usability of a monster. In case you don't know about classes and/or tiers, I'll include some more info below:

**Classes**

Pokemon "builds" can be grouped according to their function in battle (sweepers, walls, annoyers, healers, etc.). The following all work together to determine the class of a given monster:

- stats*
- ability*
- move pool
- typing*
- item

*These can change after mega evolution or because of other items like: Eviolite, Light Ball, Choice items, etc. (Stats can also change based on breeding and nurturing, but the details are too much for this answer.)

**Tiers**

Competitive battling communities (such as Smogon) have grouped Pokemon into Tiers depending on their usage for each generation. These are commonly seen as Uber, BL, OU, UU and NU. You could possibly use these groupings alongside the class to better focus your numbers/builds.